# How do I print the (numerical) ASCII values of each character in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, terminal

How can I print the numerical ASCII values of each character in a text file.  Like `cat`, but showing the ASCII values only... (hex or decimal is fine).

Example output for a file containing the word *Apple* (with a line feed) might look like:

```
065 112 112 108 101 013 004
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/od.html) command for that is `od`, for octal dump (though with options, you can change from octal to decimal or hexadecimal...):

```
$ echo Apple | od -An -vtu1
  65 112 112 108 101  10
```

Note that it outputs the byte value of every byte in the file. It has nothing to do with ASCII or any other character set.

If the file contains a A in a given character set, and you would like to see 65, because that's the byte used for A in ASCII, then you would need to do:

```
< file iconv -f that-charset -t ascii | od -An -vtu1
```

To first convert that file to ascii and then dump the corresponding byte values. For instance `Apple<LF>` in EBCDIC-UK would be `193 151 151 147 133 37` (`301 227 227 223 205 045` in octal).

```
$ printf '\301\227\227\223\205\045' | iconv -f ebcdic-uk -t ascii | od -An -vtu1
  65 112 112 108 101  10
```

Answer (score 19):

`hexdump`, `od`, `xxd`, or `$YOUR_FAVORITE_LANGUAGE` can all do that.

```
% echo Apple | hexdump -C
00000000  41 70 70 6c 65 0a                                 |Apple.|
00000006
% echo Apple | perl -ne 'printf "%vd\n", $_' 
65.112.112.108.101.10
% echo Apple | clisp <( echo '(print (mapcar #'\''char-code (coerce (read-line *standard-input*) '\''list)))' )
(65 112 112 108 101)
%
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thankyou. Especially hexdump -C. Awarded to Stephane simply because his answer also resolved, and he was first (by just a hair), but both are excellent.

Comment: Yet another command: `python -c "print open('file', 'rb').read().encode('hex')"`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Better `echo 'Apple' | python -c "import sys;print sys.stdin.read().encode('hex')"`

Comment: @heemayl : wrong. It may corrupt a binary file on Windows

Comment: @heemayl stdin uses the text mode by default that may translate newlines (`os.linesep` -> `'\n'`)